# Can someone help me debug a 'once-per-session' cookie with a addClass & removeClass function?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, addclass

I found the following JS code (not mine at all, I take no credit. Credit goes to Michael Regan,  www.owt4nowt.ca)

So, the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
var key_value = "myTestCookie=true";
var foundCookie = 0;

// Get all the cookies from this site and store in an array
var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0;i < cookieArray.length;i++)
        {
               var checkCookie = cookieArray[i];
               while (checkCookie.charAt(0)==' ')
               {
                 checkCookie = checkCookie.substring(1,checkCookie.length);
               }

                if (checkCookie.indexOf(key_value) == 0)
               {
                  alert("Found Cookie ");
                   foundCookie = 1;
               }
    }
    if ( foundCookie == 0)
    {
        document.cookie = key_value;
        alert("Setting Cookie");
    }  
</script>
```

The alerts work without fail.

However I removed the alert when the cookie is recognized:

```
        if (checkCookie.indexOf(key_value) == 0)
       {
           foundCookie = 1;
       }
```

And I replaced the "Setting Cookie" alert with an addClass function, or so I thought.

```
if ( foundCookie == 0)
{
    document.cookie = key_value;
    $('.someClassHere').addClass("newClass");
}
```

The problem is that the function does not work at all.  If it is left to only alerts, there is no problem, but the addClass function is completely ignored.

Do I have a syntax error with the addClass function?

Comment: You're missing an actual question! Did something not work? Did you get an error?

Comment: I updated the post, thank for the heads up on being vague

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use jQuery - Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: I have included the link to the Google 1.7.2 link

Comment: Can you add how you've linked to jQuery into your question.

Comment: hello again!  added to the top of the code, thanks!

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: I apologies, I had to see what the "console" was.  I got this message:   "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'reset'"

Comment: Are you doing the addClass exactly as your sample code or does your real code wait until the DOM-tree is actually loaded before trying to add the class?

Comment: the addClass is exactly how it appears in the header.  Should I instert the script after the affected object/item/tag?  Int eh example above.... after the <div class='someClassHere'></div>?

Comment: See if it works better if you wrap your cookie code in http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Hello alun!  The script works when I use your suggestion , but with a little delay, I have reorganized the CSS so that the delay isn't as disturbing as it might be, I flipped around the addClass with a removeClass and, all in all, the functionality is there!  Thanks to everyone, who helped me out

Answer (score 0):

After receiving many good comments and tips, the best result was achieved after "alun" suggested wrapping the javascript in a jQuery .ready() API.

There was a noticable delay in the script's effectiveness in adding (or removing) classes, but at least the functionality is there, with the right combination of CSS and such, the disruption can be minimized.

the resulting successful code that I used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 var key_value = "myTestCookie=true";
 var foundCookie = 0;
 var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0;i < cookieArray.length;i++)
         {
                var checkCookie = cookieArray[i];
                while (checkCookie.charAt(0)==' ')
                {
                  checkCookie = checkCookie.substring(1,checkCookie.length);
                }
                 if (checkCookie.indexOf(key_value) == 0)
                {
                    foundCookie = 1;
                }
     }
     if ( foundCookie == 0)
     {
         document.cookie = key_value;
       $('.someClassOne').removeClass("extraClass");
     } 
});
</script>
```

So, yeah, I hope this helps others!

Thanks for the forum!

/Brian